# ArcGIS webservice returning only one result when using FindAddressCandidates method

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-10.2, soap, arcgis-soap-api

I am using ArcGIS web service method FindAddressCandidates to fetch matching addresses to the provided input. But the result comes with only the top matching address. All other similar address are ignored and not shown in the result.

Some additional info:

Our primary application is based in Siebel and Siebel right now does not support/accept messages coming in JSON format. Also Siebel does not have an inbuilt converter to change the JSON to XML format. So because of this we had to use the Webservice implementation for ArcGIS instead of making a REST call.

So I was able to get the WSDL file from the url http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/soap/10.1/index.html#//01vp0000008v000000

Before implementing the whole solution in Siebel, we tried accessing it via SOAP UI. I have attached the request and response message when tested using Web service. You can see there is only one response that has come when accessed using Web Service. Also find below the response which we get with a REST call (response in JSON format), it has multiple address suggestions.

SOAP Request
[image: Soap Request]

SOAP Response
[image: Soap Response]

REST call RESPONSE

{
 "spatialReference": {
  "wkid": 4283,
  "latestWkid": 4283
 },
 "candidates": [
  {
   "address": "50 LONSDALE STREET, MELBOURNE, VIC, 3000",
   "location": {
    "x": 144.97114435763478,
    "y": -37.809456786877405
   },
   "score": 100,
   "attributes": {

},
   "extent": {
    "xmin": 144.96934571354262,
    "ymin": -37.811255430969553,
    "xmax": 144.97294300172695,
    "ymax": -37.807658142785257
   }
  },
  {
   "address": "LONSDALE STREET, MELBOURNE, VIC, 3000",
   "location": {
    "x": 144.96234167907767,
    "y": -37.812256458234671
   },
   "score": 100,
   "attributes": {

},
   "extent": {
    "xmin": 144.96054303498551,
    "ymin": -37.814055102326819,
    "xmax": 144.96414032316983,
    "ymax": -37.810457814142524
   }
  },
  {
   "address": "LONSDALE LANE, MELBOURNE, VIC, 3000",
   "location": {
    "x": 144.95865963166221,
    "y": -37.812736841323428
   },
   "score": 91.599999999999994,
   "attributes": {

},
   "extent": {
    "xmin": 144.95686098757005,
    "ymin": -37.814535485415576,
    "xmax": 144.96045827575438,
    "ymax": -37.81093819723128
   }
  }
 ]
}

Comment: I think you may be using the ArcGIS REST API, and so I have tagged your question that way.  If not, just use the [edit] button beneath your question to tell us more precisely what you are using and doing.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include more information? Can you include a code snippet, etc? At the moment, your question is quite vague and hard to debug.

Comment: to clarify, the question is essentially **how to work with the SOAP API to get multiple results**, you know there are multiple results because you can get them through the REST API, but you can't  for operational reasons use the REST API in your application

Comment: Can you add your REST request too for comparison.  Also I am confused as how you got any results because the address in the search seems to differ from the result.  Maybe I'm missing something obvious about Australian? addresses